# Javascript Click event on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Binding a click event on the item list, the box keeps disappearing. Any idea why click event not working on  item-list > div.

The idea is to fetch the text(from item-list) that is being clicked and put it in the input field ?

```js
(function() {
  $(".input-msg").focus(function() {
    $(".item-list").css('display', 'block');
    $(".item-list div").click(function() {
      var inputValue = $('.input-msg');
      var data = $(this).text();
      inputValue.val(data);
    });
  }).blur(function() {
    $(".item-list").css('display', 'none');
  });
})();
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.item-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="input-msg" placeholder="click me">
  <!-- input msg -->
  <div class="item-list">
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your question is not clear? what you exactly want to achieve? and what problem you are facing?

Comment: please explain what you're trying to do, because from reading your code, i am still not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Don't attach click listener in the focus handler, you end up to add a new listener every time the element gets the focus.

Comment: on click on the item list, its doen't insert the text, click function doesn't work ? also hide the item-list on body click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this.

```js
(function() {
  $(".item-list div").click(function() {
    var inputValue = $('.input-msg');
    var data = $(this).text();
    inputValue.val(data);
    $('.item-list').fadeOut('fast');
  });
  $(".input-msg").focus(function() {
    $(".item-list").fadeIn('fast');        
  })
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.item-list') && !$(e.target).is('.input-msg')) {
      $('.item-list').fadeOut('fast');
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.item-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="input-msg" placeholder="click me">
  <!-- input msg -->
  <div class="item-list">
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item two</div>
    <div>This is item three</div>
    <div>This is item four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @webmansa  and Kira San  why again `$(".item-list div").click(function() {` inside `focus` event handler. its really bad practice to register a listener every-time on focus of an element. Put it outside. We have already mentioned that in our answers

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks for pointing that out, I was on a hurry and didn't notice that.

Comment: @KiraSan  now the answer is perfect. so +1

Answer (score 3):

I think I got your Problem:-

1.remove `blur` code. (because it's hiding div immediately when focus out from the input-box)

2.Put `click` outside of `focus`. (register listener only one-time which is enough)

3.Inside `click` do the `hide` code. (if you want to hide div after clicking on it's text div's)

***Working snippet:-***

```js
(function() {
  $(".input-msg").focus(function() {
    $(".item-list").css('display', 'block');
    
  });
  $(".item-list div").click(function() {
      var inputValue = $('.input-msg');
      var data = $(this).text();
      inputValue.val(data);
      $('.item-list').hide();
  });
})();
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('.item-list') && !$(e.target).is('.input-msg')) {
    $('.item-list').hide(1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.item-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="input-msg" placeholder="click me">
  <!-- input msg -->
  <div class="item-list">
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item Two</div>
    <div>This is item Three</div>
    <div>This is item Four</div>
  </div>
</div><br>
```

Comment: on click outside of the div , does not hide the div container , any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

The item list disappears, because on a `blur` event triggered by the input box, the list is cleared. I've commented out the code that is hiding the list, and moved it down to happen on the item list `click`.

I've also moved the list `click` handler from inside your `blur` handler. This will prevent the click handler from being mounted again and again.

```js
(function() {
  $(".input-msg").focus(function() {
    $(".item-list").css('display', 'block');

  }).blur(function() {
 
    // THIS IS YOUR ISSUE.
    // We're going to move this line down to the 
    // `item-list` click handler.
    // $(".item-list").css('display', 'none');

  });

  // You want to register this listener once,
  // not every time user focuses on input box.
  $(".item-list div").click(function() {
    var inputValue = $('.input-msg');
    var data = $(this).text();
    inputValue.val(data);
  });

  $('.main-wrapper').children().not('.input-wrapper').click(function(){
    // Hide the item list on body click.
    // This was moved here from the `blur` handler above.
    $(".item-list").css('display', 'none');
  });

})();
```

```css
.main-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
}
  
.other-wrapper {
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
}

.input-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

.item-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="input-msg" placeholder="click me">
  <!-- input msg -->
  <div class="item-list">
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item one</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="other-wrapper">Other stuff.</div>
<div>
```

Comment: on blur , i also want to hide the item list ?

Comment: i mean on body click , outside of the item-list div hide the div ? do you understand ?

Comment: i think so, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = $("input")
const itemList = $(".item-list")
const items = $(".item-list > div")
const overlay = $(".overlay")

addClickTo(input, () => display(itemList, overlay))
addClickTo(items, (e) => {
  const itemText = e.currentTarget.textContent
  setValueOf(input, itemText)
  dontDisplay(itemList, overlay)
})
addClickTo(overlay, () => dontDisplay(itemList, overlay))


// helpers
function dontDisplay(...elements) { elements.forEach((element) => element.style.display = "none") }
function display(...elements) { elements.forEach((element) => element.style.display = "block") }
function $(selector) {
  const matchedElements = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
  return matchedElements && matchedElements.length > 1
  ? matchedElements
  : matchedElements[0]
}
function addClickTo(elements, handler) {
  elements.forEach || (elements = [elements])
  elements.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener("click", handler))
}
function setValueOf(input, text) {
    input.value = text
}
```

```js
const input = $("input")
const itemList = $(".item-list")
const items = $(".item-list > div")
const overlay = $(".overlay")

addClickTo(input, () => display(itemList, overlay))
addClickTo(items, (e) => {
  const itemText = e.currentTarget.textContent
  setValueOf(input, itemText)
  dontDisplay(itemList, overlay)
})
addClickTo(overlay, () => dontDisplay(itemList, overlay))


// helpers
function dontDisplay(...elements) { elements.forEach((element) => element.style.display = "none") }
function display(...elements) { elements.forEach((element) => element.style.display = "block") }
function $(selector) {
  const matchedElements = document.querySelectorAll(selector)
  return matchedElements && matchedElements.length > 1
  ? matchedElements
  : matchedElements[0]
}
function addClickTo(elements, handler) {
  elements.forEach || (elements = [elements])
  elements.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener("click", handler))
}
function setValueOf(input, text) {
 input.value = text
}
```

```css
.item-list {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <input type="text" class="input-msg" placeholder="click me">

  <!-- input msg -->
  <div class="item-list">
    <div>This is item one</div>
    <div>This is item two</div>
    <div>This is item three</div>
    <div>This is item four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dvekrebv/6/